# Deleting elements from an array of picture-boxes

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array of picture-boxes. In my application, it is filled as follows:
[image]

I want to delete (to remove) all the images from a specific line, like that:

```
i = 0;
while(condition(i))
{
    PB_ARRAY[line, i].Image = null;
    panel4.Controls.Remove(PB_ARRAY[line, i]);
    i++;
}
```

I tried to replace condition(i) by: PB_ARRAY[line, i].Image != null; but it doesn't work. It gives me a null-reference exception because it tries to access a non referenced object.

How can I solve that? Is there a property of a picture-box that you can check to see if it has an image different from null?

Comment: I think you need to call Remove, *before* you set the array element to null.  Right now, you set the array element to null and then try to remove "null" from the Controls collection.

Comment: which of the two lines raises the exception? And what are line and i, that is does it happen right away or only after a few deletions?
    PB_ARRAY[line, i].Image = null;
    panel4.Controls.Remove(PB_ARRAY[line, i]);

Answer (score 1):

Just add a test before calling `PB_ARRAY[line, i].Image != null` like so:

```
if (PB_ARRAY[line, i] != null && PB_ARRAY[line, i].Image != null)
    //....
```

This guards you against the null reference exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping the first two lines in your while, like this:

```
i = 0;
while(condition(i))
{
    panel4.Controls.Remove(PB_ARRAY[line, i]);
    PB_ARRAY[line, i].Image = null;
    i++;
}
```

Try posting some more code for a more precise answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the problem still exists even if I swap those two lines.

Comment: The problem persists. To be more specific: consider the line no. 1 from that dummy array that I posted above. That line contains: img2 img3 null ... null. And consider condition(i) equivalent to PB_ARRAY[line, i].Image != null. i = 0, PB_ARRAY[line, 0].Image != null (true), so it removes and sets the image property to null. i = 1, the same story. When i becomes 2, then it checks whether PB_ARRAY[line, 2].Image is different from null, but PB_ARRAY[line, 2] is not referenced, so the null reference exception raises! That is my problem! I don't know where to stop that while!

Comment: My code has over 1000 lines, the variables are named in Romanian language, the code is not properly designed so I don't think that you can understand all the things that I've done there. If you really want to see my code (but again, I don't know if you can understand something), I will post it.

Comment: Can you post the declaration of the array PB_ARRAY?

Comment: Thank you everybody for your answers.